# Sorting a JOIN by result count from bridging table

Tags: mysql, join

Abridged schema looks like

Table: Apartment

```
id | city | price ...
```

Table Amenity:

```
id | name
```

Bridging table

```
Apartment_id | Amenity_id
```

The query I am trying to construct would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM Apartment a
WHERE
a.`city` = 'foo'
AND a.`price` <= 'bar'
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) as ct FROM Bridging b
WHERE a.id = b.Aprtment_id AND
(b.Amenity_id = 'x' OR b.Amenity_id = 'y' OR b.Amenity_id = 'z')
ORDER BY ct DESC
```

If I did this in the code I could iterate over the found apartments, query the amenity matches and add that count to a field in the objects and sort on that before paginating but this seems very in elegant.

Is the a clean way to query the Aprtment records ordered by the # of matching rows in the Bridging table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Apartment a
    JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as ct, Apartment_id
    FROM Bridging
    WHERE Amenity_id IN ('x','y','z')
    GROUP BY Apartment_id 
    ) b ON a.id = b.Apartment_id 
WHERE
    a.`city` = 'foo'
    AND a.`price` <= 'bar'
ORDER BY
    b.bt DESC
```

Comment: You are the man!  Thank you!  Note, should read COUNT(*) as ct, Apartment_id

Comment: Thanks, fixed my dodgy copy/paste

Comment: If you come to New Orleans I owe you beverages of choice!